# Using NeatReceipts for the PC on my Mac

Tags: macos, scanner

I was recently given a brand new [NeatReceipts scanner](http://www.neatco.com/products/neatreceipts).  However, the version given to me was for Windows, and contained the Windows software.  I'm a Mac user, and need the Mac software.

Is there any way I can get the Mac NeatReceipts software without having to re-buy the entire system or pay again for the Mac software?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crazy, I just talked to NeatRecipts support and ... got a reasonable answer. I'm shocked.

Turns out certain mode scanners are PC only "at the hardware level" (whatever that really means), but that they'll gladly do a swap out for a Mac version if you want.

Comment: strange, according to the FAQ, they're the same scanners, the software makes the difference: http://www.neatco.com/products/common-questions#NRMac